# To find the determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $A_{n\times n}$=$(a_{ij}),$ n $\ge$ 3, where $a_{ij}$ = $b_{i}^{2}$-$b_{j}^2$ ,$i,j = 1,2,...,n$ for some distinct real numbers $b_{1},b_{2},...,b_{n}$. I have to find the determinant of A. I can see that A is a skew-symmetric matrix. So determinant of A is $0$ when n is odd. But how to find it when n is even? Is the condition given for A implies anything other than A is skew-symmetric?

Comment: $n = 4$ is even, did you try it for this case?

Comment: Yes,It is zero. But is there anyway to prove it for a general n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the rows of your matrix are linear combinations of the vector $u=(b_1^2,b_2^2,\ldots,b_n^2)$ and $v=(1,1,\ldots,1)$. More precisely, row number #$i$ is equal to $b_i^2v-u$.

Therefore the row space of the matrix is at most 2-dimensional, so the matrix has rank $\le2$. As the number of rows is $\ge3$, the matrix is singular and its determinant is $=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v := \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{b_2^2 - b_3^2}{b_2^2 - b_1^2} &
\dfrac{b_1^2 - b_3^2}{b_1^2 - b_2^2} &
-1 &
0 &
\ldots &
0
\end{bmatrix}^T$ if $b_1^2 \ne b_2^2$, or else
$v := \begin{bmatrix}
1 &
-1 & 
0 &
\ldots &
0
\end{bmatrix}^T$. Then $Av = 0$, so $\ker A \ne 0 \implies \det A = 0$.

---

Proof of $Av = 0$: Let $r_j := \begin{bmatrix}b_j^2 - b_1^2 & b_j^2 - b_2^2 & \ldots & b_j^2 - b_n^2\end{bmatrix}$ be the $j^\text{th}$ row of $A$. If $b_1^2 \ne b_2^2$,
$$r_j v = (b_j^2 - b_1^2)\left(\frac{b_2^2 - b_3^2}{b_2^2 - b_1^2}\right) + (b_j^2 - b_2^2)\left(\frac{b_1^2 - b_3^2}{b_1^2 - b_2^2}\right) + (b_j^2 - b_3^2)(-1)$$
is a linear polynomial in the variable $b_j^2$ which vanishes at $b_1^2$ and $b_2^2$, hence is identically zero. If $b_1^2 = b_2^2$, then 
$r_jv = (b_j^2 - b_1)^2(1) + (b_j^2 - b_2^2)(-1) = 0$.

Comment: OP: Although I've given you a concrete answer, I recommend that you accept (and upvote) Jyrki's answer (as well as accepting + upvoting previous answers to your questions)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The coefficients of the characteristic equation satisfied by $A$ are given by the equation: $c_{n} = - \frac{1}{n} \left(c_{n-1}\mathrm{Trace}(A) + c_{n-2}\mathrm{Trace}(A^{2})+ ... + c_{1}\mathrm{Trace}(A^{n-1}) + \mathrm{Trace}(A^{n}) \right)$ with $c_{0} = 1$. Now the conditions in the problem imply that $\mathrm{Trace}(A^{k}) = 0$. Now, use the Cayley-Hamilton's Theorem to conclude that $\det(A) = 0$.

Comment: We have to see that Trace(A^k)=0 only by computation or is there any other way to see it?

Comment: The trace is usually defined as the sum of the diagonal entries. Your diagonal entries are $a_{ii} = 0$. How does taking powers affect the diagonal entries? Your diagonal are zeros and they will remain zero in $A^{k}$ for all $k = 1, 2, 3,...$.

Comment: Here $c_{n}$ denotes the constant term in the characteristic polynomial, right?If it is so then $c_{n}$ = det A, it means det(A)=0 when trace A =0 ? I am quite confused

Comment: Yes, $c_{n}$ are the coefficients in the characteristic polynomial. I would double check the precise statement of the Cayley-Hamilton's Theorem if I were you.

Comment: $\text{Trace}(A^k)$ need not be $0$ for all $k$ - indeed, this happens iff $A$ is nilpotent

Comment: Something is wrong here. Your argument cannot possibly work. For if it did, then the claim would also work when $n=2$. But the claim is false, when $n=2$. $b_1=1$, $b_2=0$ gives
$$A=\pmatrix{0&1\cr-1&0\cr}.$$ In that case $A^2=-I$, so its trace is $-2$. Also $\det A=1$.